# Invalid arguments passed - Was working, now it is not

Tags: php

I've had this code working for a few years and now I don't believe any changes were made but a few days ago it just stopped working and started giving me this error:

> Warning: implode() [function.implode]: Invalid arguments passed in
>   /home/vss/public_html/dashboard/modules/addons/vssapp/classes/class.adminarea.php
>   on line 277
>
> Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted
>   to string in
>   /home/vss/public_html/dashboard/modules/addons/vssapp/dropbox/Dropbox/OAuth/Consumer/Curl.php
>   on line 102

**class.adminarea.php**:

```
       foreach($imagedata as $image){
            $data = '';
            $sizes = getimagesize($image['path'].'?dl=false');
            $data .= 'Filename: '."".$image['filename']."\n";
            $data .= 'Image Size:' ."".$sizes[0].'px x '.$sizes[1].'px'."\n";
            $data .= 'Path: '."".$image['path'].'?dl=false'."\n";
            $data .= 'Rooms: '." ".ucwords(implode(", ", array_keys(unserialize($image['rooms']))))."\n";
            if($image['couch'] != ''){$data .= 'Couch Position: '."".$image['couch']."\n";}
            if($image['headboard'] != ''){$data .= 'Headboard Position: '."".$image['headboard']."\n";}
            if($image['generaldiningroom'] != ''){$data .= 'Dining Room Position: '."".$image['generaldiningroom']."\n";}
            if($image['generallivingroom'] != ''){$data .= 'Living Room Position: '."".$image['generallivingroom']."\n";}
            $data .= 'Furniture: '."".implode(", ", unserialize($image['furniture']))."\n";
            $data .= 'Info: '."".$image['info']."\n\n--------------------------\n\n";
            $imagedetails[] = $data;
        }
```

**Curl.php**:

```
        // Check if an error occurred and throw an Exception
    if (!empty($response['body']->error)) {
        $message = $response['body']->error . ' (Status Code: ' . $response['code'] . ')';
        throw new \Dropbox\Exception($message);
    }

    return $response;
}
```

Any thoughts on what happened and how to fix it?

Comment: Can you add it to 3v4l.org for us to look at? 3v4l allows you to run it against lots of different versions so you can see at what point it broke.

Comment: "Don't believe any changes were made" - that sounds like the first thing to nail down - what does source-control say?

Comment: @NeilMasters: https://3v4l.org/mBiqW

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth - no source control on this and I'm the only one with access. I think it is more likely that something else happened. This integrates with Dropbox API and Google drive API so I'm wondering if maybe one of those is causing it. Really not sure at this point though.

Comment: The line being referenced "invalid argument" error is the furniture line :     `$data .= 'Furniture: '."".implode(", ", unserialize($image['furniture']))."\n";`

Comment: Michael, you have created an 3v4l but you need to make it work so it executes. Currently the 3v4l does not actually execute anything :)